# LibreOffice Impress does not load the installed fonts

Tags: font, font-book, libreoffice

I'm trying to use LaTeX fonts in my LibreOffice Impress presentation so I downloaded the lmroman12 fonts from [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm/) and installed them via font-book. But when I open a document containing the font it does not load them hinting:

> the current font is not available and will be substituted

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

P.S. I wasn't sure if this is a LibreOffice issue or mac one so I tried here first.

Comment: Tried downloading the lmroman12 font (only the regular version) and installed it on MacOs (10.11.6). It appears in the fontbook as "Latin Roman Regular". Afterwards I launched LibreOffice and I could use it in a slide without any problems... are you sure you downloaded all the "versions" of the font you need?

Comment: @GioValerio Then I must be doing something wrong! How do I check if My fonts are installed properly? I opened font-book, searched for the Latin..., all of them are there!

Comment: You can check if they are available in another MacOs app (like TextEdit) and/or try like I did, open Impress, create a new presentation, and see if when you modify the font of a text (box) you have the choice to use the Latin Modern font.

Comment: @GioValerio I tested in TextEdit, They work properly there. But not LO Impress!

Comment: sorry if it sounds stupid, but you did close LibreOffice completely before testing it, didn't you? Because the suite checks the font list at startup... Worst case, try rebooting the Mac.

Comment: @GioValerio yes, I actually restarted the laptop a couple of times too!

Comment: Which version of OS and LibreOffice are you using?

Comment: @GioValerio  `OS X El Capitan 10.11.6` and LO --> `5.4.5.1`

Comment: I am using LO  6.0.0.3... not sure if there was any font related issued in the previous release... but even in an old (4.0) OpenOffice i can use the fonts in Impress...